# Does dwscript support operator overloading

Tags: operator-overloading, dwscript

I know dwscript has operator overloading for compound operators `+=` etc.

I would like to have operator overloading for `+`, `-` etc as well for use in addition, multiplication etc. of matrix objects.
Does dwscript support this?

And if so what this the syntax do overload an operator?

Comment: This might be more appropriate as an entry in the DWScript issue tracker on googlecode. Currently they aren't supported script-side, Delphi-side the major structures are in place, but there are no convenience APIs, and no unit tests on that aspect (though they are planned).

Comment: @eric, thanks I wasn't sure of the status of this issue in DWScript, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of last week, binary operators overloading is supported and tested, both script-side (user-specified operator overloading) and Delphi-side (built-in operator overloading).

For the syntax, see [here](http://delphitools.info/2011/08/05/xe2-dws-2-2-rosetta-code-operators/) and [there](http://delphitools.info/2010/12/24/everythings-got-to-end-some-day/).